# Unable to connect to WiFi hotspot

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian

I am unable to connect to the AP of the NanoPi's wifi. I'm not able to understand what seems to be the issue?

**hostapd.conf**

```
hw_mode=g
channel=1
driver=nl80211

ssid=nanopi2-wifiap
interface=wlan0

wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=123456789
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
```

**dhcpd.conf**

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.55.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
      range 192.168.55.200 192.168.55.254;
}
```

I looked up to these links [link[1]](https://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/) and [links[2]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36693/cant-connect-to-my-rpi-access-point). I tried the way it was in the link. I was able to start the WiFi hotspot. But unable to connect to it.

What could be the issue here?